# Php message updater clearing row instead of updating it

Tags: php, sql, post, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am using the following script to process a form that updates a message on my website, the problem I am having is that it is clearing the row instead of updating it for some reason. I have copied the query from Phpmyadmin so I know its correct, and I have also tried echoing the posted values and they all echo out just fine too, but for some unknown reason when I click submit in the form it just wipes the contents of the record instead of updating it.

```
<?php
    include("connectmysqli.php");

    if (isset($_POST['OnOff'])) {$OnOff = $_POST['OnOff'];}else {$OnOff = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['title'])) {$title = $_POST['title'];}else {$title = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['message'])) {$message = $_POST['message'];}else {$message = '';}

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `itsnb_chronoforms_data_urgentform` SET  `title` =  '$title',`message` =  '$message',`OnOff` =  '$OnOff' WHERE `cf_id` =1;");
    if (!$stmt) trigger_error($db->error);
    $stmt->execute(); 

    echo 'Message Updated !';
    echo '<p><a href="index.php?&key='.$key.'">Back To Main Menu</a></p>';
    ?>
```

This is the table :

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use prepared statements?

Comment: Wouldst that be slightly overkill for this, its just a simple post form data script.

Comment: Prepared statements is not "overkill", but **strict requirement**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you echo the generated query?

there are exactly to ways I see this can happen:

1. your form input names do not match the post keys you check in the three if statements
2. you're not sending the form with method="post"

also you should only execute the update query if all three post fields are set and valid. like title and message must not be blank/empty and that onOff variable should eighter contain "on" or "off". otherwise echo an errormessage so the user knows what's wrong with his input.

Comment: If I echo >> echo 'The Message Is Now : '.$OnOff;
echo '<br/>';
echo 'You Set The Title : '.$title;
echo '<br/>';
echo 'You Set The Message : '.$message;

It brings up all the data I just posted.

Comment: do this: `echo "UPDATE \`itsnb_chronoforms_data_urgentform\` SET  \`title\` =  '$title',\`message\` =  '$message',\`OnOff\` =  '$OnOff' WHERE \`cf_id\` =1;"`

Comment: That gives me :  UPDATE itsnb_chronoforms_data_urgentform` SET title = 'this is the title',message = 'this is the message',OnOff = 'On' WHERE cf_id =1;

Comment: well, then the error is obviously not in this part of of the the code ;) what does `var_dump($stmt->execute());` print out?

Comment: That gives me : bool(true)

Comment: Can this be caused by a server problem ?, as the form is so basic there isnt really anywhere else to look.

Comment: should not be a server problem. did you try to execute the echoed query in phpmyadmin or something?

Comment: Yes, thats where I got it from to begin with, if I do it in Phpmyadmin it works just fine.

Comment: are you sure there are no other queries affecting the data?

Comment: Yes, thats the whole submit form above, nothing else happens after that.

Comment: 1. you posted the generated query which looks fine / 2. the same query in phpmyadmin works. / 3. $stmt->execute(); returns true / 4. no other code is executed. / this seems quite impossible to me :)

Comment: I thought the same thing :-S

Comment: It gets even stranger as if I the follwing, this works just fine and inserts a record, I just cant seem to update an existing one. $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `itsnb_chronoforms_data_urgentform` (`title`,`message`, `OnOff`) VALUES ('$title', '$message', '$OnOff');");
if (!$stmt) trigger_error($db->error);
$stmt->execute();

Comment: Ok, so I tried using PDO instead and get the same result so I know its nothing to do with MYSQLI